# Converting Arbitrarily Nested Dict to List of Lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to convert a nested dict data structure into a flat list of lists, and I can't come up with a good solution.  Here's the data I am starting with, and the output I want to generate.  What I want to do is come up with a `flatten` function that works regardless of how deep the input data is nested.

```
input_dict_1 = {"data": [
    {"gender": "male",
     "data": [
         {"age": "adult",
          "data": {"average_height": 62, "average_weight": 200}},
         {"age": "youth",
          "data": {"average_height": 50, "average_weight": 120}}]},
    {"gender": "female",
     "data": [
         {"age": "adult",
          "data": {"average_height": 55, "average_weight": 130}},
         {"age": "youth",
          "data": {"average_height": 45, "average_weight": 80}},
         {"age": "infant",
          "data": {"average_height": 15, "average_weight": 35}}]}]}

output_array_1 = flatten(input_dict_1)

# output_array_1 = [["gender", "age", "average_height", "average_weight"],
#                   ["male", "adult", 62, 200],
#                   ["male", "youth", 50, 120],
#                   ["female", "adult", 55, 130],
#                   ["female", "youth", 45, 80],
#                   ["female", "infant", 15, 35]]

input_dict_2 = {"data": [
    {"animal": "bunny",
     "data": [
         {"color": "white",
          "data": [
              {"age": "adult",
               "data": {"speed": 30, "teeth": 24}},
              {"age": "youth",
               "data": {"speed": 20, "teeth": 24}}]}]},
    {"animal": "horse",
     "data": [
         {"color": "brown",
          "data": [
              {"age": "adult",
               "data": {"speed": 120, "teeth": 6}}]}]}]}

output_array_2 = flatten(input_dict_2)

# output_array_1 = [["animal", "color", "age", "speed", "teeth"],
#                   ["bunny", "white", "adult", 30, 24],
#                   ["bunny", "white", "youth", 20, 24],
#                   ["horse", "brown", "adult", 120, 6]]
```

It's not too hard if you know how many levels deep the structure goes ahead of time, but I'm stuck on how to write a single function that works for arbitrarily nested input data.

There are a couple of conditions to which the input data will always conform:

1. The number of levels will always be the same within a single input
   data structure.  For instance, in a longer version of the
   `input_dict_1` example there would never be a third grouping level
   beyond gender and age.
2. At each level, the next subgroup is the value
   for a key with the name `data`.

There's got to be an elegant, pythonic solution for this.  Any ideas?

(The context here is I'm trying to convert JSON I receive from an API into a CSV file, but this is the only hard part.  Also, I know there are already a bunch of questions on SO dealing with dicts to lists, but I was not able to find one that uses a similar input/output structure.)

Comment: Do you atleast know the headers `"gender", "age", "average_height", "average_weight"` beforehand?

Comment: No, the column headers can be different and I can't easily predict them ahead of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the kind of question where recursion is your friend. As a first example we can write a function to grab the column names that we'll need from one of your inputs,

```
input_dict_1 = {"data": [
    {"gender": "male",
     "data": [
         {"age": "adult",
          "data": {"average_height": 62, "average_weight": 200}},
         {"age": "youth",
          "data": {"average_height": 50, "average_weight": 120}}]},
    {"gender": "female",
     "data": [
         {"age": "adult",
          "data": {"average_height": 55, "average_weight": 130}},
         {"age": "youth",
          "data": {"average_height": 45, "average_weight": 80}},
         {"age": "infant",
          "data": {"average_height": 15, "average_weight": 35}}]}]}

def get_col_names( d, l=None ):
    if l==None: l=[]
    if isinstance(d['data'], list):
        l.extend( k for k in d['data'][0].keys() if k != 'data' )
        get_col_names( d['data'][0], l )
    else:
        l.extend( d['data'].keys() )
    return l
```

The above example was just to get you thinking about recursion.  We can get the column names and visit all the key value pairs we want in one function,

```
def walk_dict( d, e=None, l=None, cn=None ):
    if e==None: e={}
    if l==None: l=[]
    if cn==None: cn=[]
    for k,v in d.items():
        if k != 'data':
            if k not in cn: cn.append(k)
            e[k] = v
    if isinstance(d['data'], list):
        for dp in d['data']:
            walk_dict( dp, e, l, cn )
    else:
        for k,v in d['data'].items():
            if k not in cn: cn.append(k)
            e[k] = v
        l.append( e.copy() )
    return l, cn
```

In the above function, `e` represents the current row being gathered, `l` is a list of all rows parsed so far, and `cn` is a list of the column names.  Finally some code to build the list of lists you want,

```
rows, col_names = walk_dict( input_dict_1 )
output_array_1 = [col_names]
for d in rows:
    output_array_1.append( [d[name] for name in col_names] )
```

So what's going on here?  `e` keeps track of the current row keys and values.  This means it will only ever have 4 key-value pairs in it (for this input).  We want `"gender":"male"` to persist while we go through `"age":"adult"` and `"age":"youth"`.  This is a perfect fit for a dictionary.  Initially the entries in each row will be unordered.  Once `col_names` is built we can use it to pull out the entries in each row in the order we like.

Why do we use `e.copy()` instead of just `e`?  This brushes up against an aspect of Python that can be very confusing if you're not aware of it.  If you just append `e` to a list you will get a reference to the object `e`.  If you change `e`, the reference in the list will point to the changed `e`.  This would result in all rows being equal to the key:value pairs for the final row.  BUT by doing `e.copy()` we are telling Python to make a new object and append it to the list.  Then we can update `e` without affecting what is already in our list.

`col_names` will be ordered according to the nesting of the input dict except for the final dictionary keys ( i.e. `average_height` and `average_weight` ) as the order in which dictionary keys are accessed is arbitrary.

Comment: This is great stuff.  Two minor questions: why `l.append(e.copy())` rather than `l.append(e)` ?  And why build `e` as a dict rather than a list?  Is that because you can't know the right order until you have the column names built?

Comment: I'll add reasons to the answer.